# Joomla Chronoforms Dynamic To

Tags: joomla

I have successfully created a basic Chronoforms form with the standard 'To' field sending the form data in an email to one recipient.  However, I would like the 'To' field to become a 'Dynamic To' that will send the form to different users based off of the value of one of the dropdown fields I have in the form.  I couldn't find any good documentation on how to use the 'Dynamic To' or accomplish this.
Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

In chronoform you use the dynamic fields simply by writing the name of the form field into the respective E-Mail field.

So if the name of your dropdown is `email_choice` you write `email_choice` into the "Dynamic To" field of the E-Mail setup box and you're good to go.

Comment: Tharkun,
thanks for the quick response.  The issue is that my dropdown is a list of sports.  I need to basically set an email address to correlate with each item in the dropdown though.  Normally this could be done simply through a case statement or series of if statements, but I'm not sure if this is possible to do in Chronoforms itself.
Thanks again for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can set the options of the dropdown list as sports and the values as email addresses: `<option value="email@domain.com">sport</option>`

Answer (score 0):

How to show a drop down list of email recipients without displaying the email addresses publicly:

**1. ChronoForms v3**

Your drop down list in your HTML code will look something like this:

```
<div class="form_item">
  <div class="form_element cf_dropdown">
    <label class="cf_label" style="width: 150px;">Person to Contact:</label>
    <select class="cf_inputbox" id="select_0" size="1" title=""  name="Attn">
      <option value="">Choose Option</option>
      <option value="President">President</option>
      <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
      <option value="Treasurer">Treasurer</option>
      etc
```

Enter this code in the 'On Submit code - before sending email' field:

```
<?php
  $email_list = array(
    'President'=>'president@organisation.com',
    'Secretary'=>'secretary@organisation.com',
    'Treasurer'=>'treasurer@organisation.com'
  );
  $MyForm =& CFChronoForm::getInstance('Contact');
  $MyFormEmails =& CFEMails::getInstance($MyForm->formrow->id);
  $MyFormEmails->setEmailData(1, 'to', $email_list[$_POST['Attn']]);
?>
```

This assumes your form name is "Contact".

In "Setup Emails", enter "Attn" in the "To" field.

**2. ChronoForms v4**

Your drop down list in your HTML code will look something like this:

```
<div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_select" id="who_to_contact__container_div">
  <label for="Who">Who to Contact:</label>
  <select size="1" label_over="0" hide_label="0" id="Who" class=" validate['required']" title="Who" type="select" name="Who">
    <option value="President">President</option>
    <option value="Secretary">Secretary</option>
    <option value="Treasurer">Treasurer</option>
    etc
```

Enter some Custom Code In the Submit section with "Mode" set to "Controller":

```
<?php
  $who = JRequest::getString('Who', 'Webmaster', 'post');
  $emails = array(
    'President' => 'president@organisation.com',
    'Secretary' => 'secretary@organisation.com',
    'Treasurer' => 'treasurer@organisation.com'
  );
  $form->data['Attn'] = $emails[$who];
?>
```

In Email -> Dynamic, set "Dynamic To" to: Attn

**References:**

- http://chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15263&p=45265
- http://chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=16272&p=42909
- http://chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=16839&p=45601